# StackOverflowException while mapping in NEST

Tags: c#, stack-overflow, nest

I'm new to Elastic Search/NEST. Currently I am trying to get the following Class mapped:

```
[ElasticType(
  Name = "zData",
  SearchAnalyzer = "standard",
  IndexAnalyzer = "standard",
  DateDetection = false,
  NumericDetection = true

)]
public class zData {

    [ElasticProperty(Type = FieldType.string_type)]
    public String zName {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [ElasticProperty(Type = FieldType.string_type)]
    public String zType {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [ElasticProperty(Type = FieldType.nested)]
    public List<zData> Items {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [ElasticProperty(Type = FieldType.string_type)]
    public String Value {
        get;
        set;
        }
    }
```

First I tried to completely map it automatically. Later I tried to create a Mapping by myself, which is mostly like the the one from the test project on github:

```
var r = IndexClient.MapFluent<zData>(z => z
            .TypeName("zData")
            .IndexNames("testdata")
            .IgnoreConflicts()
            .IndexAnalyzer("standard")
            .SearchAnalyzer("standard")
            .DateDetection(false)
            .NumericDetection(false)
            .MapFromAttributes()
            .DisableAllField(false)
            .DisableIndexField(false)
            .DisableSizeField(false)
            .Dynamic()
            .Enabled()
            .Path("full")
            .Properties(props => props
                .Object<zData>(s => s
                    .Name(p => p.Items.First())
                    .Dynamic()
                    .Enabled()
                    .IncludeInAll()
                    .MapFromAttributes()
                    .Path("full")
                    .Properties(pprops => pprops
                        .String(ps => ps.Name(p => p.zName).Index(FieldIndexOption.not_analyzed))
                        .String(ps => ps.Name(p => p.zType).Index(FieldIndexOption.not_analyzed))
                        .String(ps => ps.Name(p => p.Value).Index(FieldIndexOption.not_analyzed))
                    )
                )
                .NestedObject<zData>(s => s
                    .Name(p => p.Items.First())
                    .Dynamic()
                    .Enabled()
                    .IncludeInAll()
                    .IncludeInParent()
                    .IncludeInRoot()
                    .MapFromAttributes()
                    .Path("full")
                    .Properties(pprops => pprops
                                .String(ps => ps.Name(p => p.zName).Index(FieldIndexOption.not_analyzed))
                                .String(ps => ps.Name(p => p.zType).Index(FieldIndexOption.not_analyzed))
                                .String(ps => ps.Name(p => p.Value).Index(FieldIndexOption.not_analyzed))
                    )
                )
            )
        );
```

I'm not sure if this mapping is convenient for my case. The Exception I get is the following:

```
Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException
```

After closing the program, I get a message from Visual Studio, that the exception happened in the mscorlib.dll.

I know that the problem is because of an endless loop. A zData object can have a list of zData, which can have a list of zData each and so on. But is there any command, which tells NEST not to go deeper than the first list, for example? Maybe somebody knows an alternative structure of zData, which is as flexible as the current, but is more save to map?

Edit1: The new mapping

```
var mapping = IndexClient.MapFluent<zData>(m => m
            .IgnoreConflicts()
            .Dynamic()
            .Enabled()
            .IncludeInAll()
            .DisableAllField(false)
            .DisableIndexField(false)
            .DisableSizeField(false)
            .Path("full")
            .AnalyzerField(a => a
                .SetPath(p => p.zName)
                .SetIndexed()
            )
            .TypeField(t => t
                .SetIndexed()
                .SetStored()
            )
            .Properties(p => p
                .String(s => s
                    .Name(n => n.zName)
                    .IndexName("name")
                    .IncludeInAll()
                    .Index(FieldIndexOption.analyzed)
                    .SearchAnalyzer("standard")
                    .Store()
                )
                .String(s => s
                    .Name(n => n.zType)
                    .IndexName("ztype")
                    .IncludeInAll()
                    .Index(FieldIndexOption.analyzed)
                    .SearchAnalyzer("standard")
                    .Store()
                )
                .String(s => s
                    .Name(n => n.Value)
                    .IndexName("value")
                    .IncludeInAll()
                    .Index(FieldIndexOption.analyzed)
                    .SearchAnalyzer("standard")
                    .Store()
                )
                .NestedObject<zData>(z => z
                    .Name(n => n.Items.First())
                    .Dynamic()
                    .Enabled()
                    .IncludeInAll()
                    .Path("full")
                    .Properties(pp => pp
                        .String(ps => ps
                            .Name(na => na.zName)
                            .Index(FieldIndexOption.not_analyzed)
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

The `MapFromAttributes()` recursively walks the complete object graph which by default has no recursionLimit.

Luckily you can give it one though with `MapFromAttributes(maxRecursion:1)`.

Comment: Thank you that is, what I was searching for, but the exception is still comming :(

Comment: I notice you call map from attributes in multiple places did you update all of them?

Comment: I tried do build a mapping without the MapFromAttributes calls. Now I don't get any StackOverflow Exceptions anymore, but the Mapping seems not to be valid. I edited the new mapping at the end of my initial question. What is missing to get a valid mapping?